# Update a List of values with empty string and keep value in other fields

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list in the form-

```
FieldName-      DataType-
Date            DateTime
DateString      String
Unit            double
Price           double
```

I want to perform an operation such that if weakday on `Date` is not Monday then update `DateString` with empty string otherwise keep the value of `DateString` as it is.

Data is present in List.

**UPDATE**
I have applied aggregate function on DataTable dtGas as follows-

```
var qGas = from x in dtGas.AsEnumerable()
                       group x by new
                       {
                           Date = x.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                           DateString = x.Field<string>("DateString")
                       } into egroup
                       select new
                       {
                           Date = egroup.Key.Date,
                           DateString = egroup.Key.DateString,
                           Unit = egroup.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Unit")),
                           Price = egroup.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Price"))
                       };
```

Now I need to show this result into Chart. Due to large amount of data values are overlapping on X-axis.

That is why I need to remove some values from DateString and show only few of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use conditional operator like this:-

```
group x by new
      {
          Date = x.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
          DateString = x.Field<string>("DateString")
       } into egroup
let isMonday = egroup.Key.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Monday"
select new
      {
          Date = egroup.Key.Date,
          DateString = isMonday ? egroup.Key.DateString : "",
          ..other properties
```

Comment: that worked awesome! I have need to take one step further. What if I want to always return the first and last value. And for the rest return only that are Monday?

Comment: Didn't get you, when you want to return first or last value? When it's Monday?

Comment: Even better and reliable idea  I am thinking is to 1. Always return first and last value in this field(regardless of day etc). 2. Return random values from the list (leaving few in between blank) so that total values returned count is 20(max number of text which can be shown in x axis to avoid overlapping).

Comment: @kamalpreet - That itself seems to be a big requirement, you should post a new question by specifying what you have tried. As far as this question is concerned, I have already answered your question, but can modify slightly as per your need not completely.

Comment: Here's my new question. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664962/c-sharp-list-to-return-values-in-intervals-for-a-specific-field